# qTranslate Importer "Please save the qTranslate settings to the database first"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-deployment

I am developing multilingual site in wordpress, i need to translate site contents in Arabic,

here i am using `qTranslate Importer` but this error is coming every time

```
"Please save the qTranslate settings to the datbase first".
```

even i am following this [Documentation](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/qtranslate-importer/)
 Please help me in this regard or suggest me is there any other way to translate contents of Wordpress Site? (Any Plugin for WP 3.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this according to my need...

[polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)

Answer (score 5):

My guess: You've installed qTranslate Importer instead [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/)

Comment: glad my guess was right :) BTW, they have wrong link on their page.

Comment: Than what should i do?

Comment: De install plugin, install one from my link http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/) . I believe this is what you are looking for

Comment: i don't want to use Google translator, cause it not translates accurately (not grammatically)